# Nodejs - can't find the .node_libraries folder

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js, I would like to use **Step.js**

https://github.com/creationix/step

The install instructions are very simple:

**"Simply copy or link the lib/step.js file into your $HOME/.node_libraries folder."**

The problem is that **I can't find the .node_libraries folder anywhere**.
I tried to create the folder myself and upload the step.js file but I get the following error:

*ReferenceError: Step is not defined*

I tried to create the following directories:

- home/service/.node_libraries
- root/.node_libraries
- /usr/local/bin/.node_libraries

but none of them works.

Also, Is it possible to load Step as a module?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have an npm [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/step).

Simply run `npm install --save step` in the same dir your `package.json` resides and then you can `require()` it in your code like this:

```
var Step = require('step');
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is outdated.
you should use the node package manager.

open the command line in the folder and write:

```
npm install step
```

also remember to include the module in your javascript file:

```
var Step = require('step');
```